# How do I merge these Kotlin flows?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Consider the following methods:

```
// Returns a Flows of integers. Each integer is a unique id for a Foo.
// Emits a new integer whenever the current Foo changes.
suspend fun getCurrentFooId(): Flow<Int>
```

```
// Returns a Foo.
// Emits a new Foo if the internal state of the last Foo changes.
suspend fun getFooForId(int: fooId): Flow<Foo>
```

What I need is a `Flow<Foo>` that emits a new `Foo` if the current `Foo` id changes ***OR*** the internal state of the current `Foo` changes.

I can't just merge the `Flow`s because I can't call `getFooForId()` until ***after*** I start collecting on the first `Flow` (because it provides the `Foo` ids).

Should I use a channel flow to merge them concurrently or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It would be

```
val fooFlow: Flow<Foo> = getCurrentFooId().flatMapLatest { getFooForId(it) }
```

"Flat map" means for each item in the source flow, emit all the items of the produced flow from the lambda. And "latest" means each time the source flow emits a new value, skip ahead to the newly produced flow.

In practice, your two functions should not be marked `suspend`. It typically doesn't require calling any blocking or suspend functions to produce a flow, and it's a lot more flexible to be able to get a flow without having to do it in a coroutine. Often you might want to get a flow and collect it using `launchIn` so you don't have to nest it in a coroutine, or use `shareIn` to create a hot flow. Especially useful if you're going to be assigning it to a class property.